# How to write a file using LF instead of CRLF on Windows?

Tags: node.js

We have a script that runs as the preinstall script. It uses fs.writeFile to write a config file which it generates.

```
writeFile(configFilePath, configFileContents, (e) => {
    // ... do some error handling
}
```

For some reason it uses CRLF line endings on Windows and creating diffs in git although the file has not changed.

I have tried to do use

```
.replace(/\r\n/gm, "\n");
```

on `configFileContents` but it still uses the Windows line endings.

`configFileContents` gets created by:

```
const configFileContents = JSON.stringify({
  foo: bar,
  baz, foo,
  // ...
}, null, 2);
```

Is there a way to tell Node to use the Linux ones?

Comment: I try your code and get `LF` line ending

Comment: That is weird. We simply create an object, stringify it with the code above and it saves using Windows line endings.

Comment: Try `console.log(configFileContents.includes('\r'));`, `true` or `false`?

Comment: Why you said `it uses CRLF line endings on Windows`

Comment: I made a mistake, my bad. As it seems someone pushed something with the Windows line endings and the script generated it with Linux line endings. I read the diff wrong and assumed it was my machine who did this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```js
.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n")
```

Also `/\r\n/gm` regexp isn't correct as you're already telling the Regexp engine to look for new line by providing the `m`/multiple lines option... That's why it doesn't allow the expression to work. Just use `g` if you really wan't to use the RegExp

Comment: Could you be more clear, please.. I didn't get what you were trying to say

Comment: `'\r\n abc\r\n'.replace(/\r\n/gm, "\n").includes('\r')` is `false`, `'\r\n abc\r\n'.replace("\r\n", "\n").includes('\r')` is `true`.  You answer cannot remove all `\r`

Comment: well, there's a option that I don't know very clearly..is using `require('os').EOL`. I think this shouldn't help but worth trying... This behavior usuallly happens if that file is edited by any editor which is using CRLF line breaks instead of LF. If you're using VSCode then you can change it from the bottom tool bar. This will allow editing the file in LF mode

Comment: I made a mistake, my bad. As it seems someone pushed something with the Windows line endings and the script generated it with Linux line endings. I read the diff wrong and assumed it was my machine who did this.

Comment: Mistake happens, no worry

Answer (score 0):

I used prettier to update the file automatically after the file was created, that worked for me. So i just added prettier command in extention to the file creation npm script.

```
prettier \"supportedBrowsers.ts\" --write"
```

[image]